# Is there a transformItems equivalent in the Android Java Libraries for Algolia?

Tags: android, transform, algolia, instantsearch

I have a use case where i would like to render the image associated with the hits returned from an Algolia search using the Algolia Java library for Android. I am currently developing on Pie . Here is what i am doing :

1. I use com.algolia.instantsearch.core.helpers.Searcher
2. I bind the results to a fragment which has a layout with the algolia attributes for images

   ```
   <ImageView
        algolia:attribute='@{"image_url"}'
   >
   ```
3. The trouble is that the response JSON only stores the name of the JPG image which needs to be displayed. I need to dynamically add the base site URL and some more path specifiers . I tried doing something like this

   `algolia:attribute='https://somedomain.com/somepath1/ProductImages/@{"BaseProductId"}/thumbnails/@{"image_url"}`

   But that was not accepted.
4. I am looking for a way to transform the results so i can build the complete URL and place it in the image_url and then use it in the layout as stated in the first code fragment.

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a listener and updating the hits object as seen below.

```
 searcher.registerResultListener(new AlgoliaResultsListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResults(@NonNull SearchResults results, boolean isLoadingMore) {
                     for (int i=0;i<results.hits.length();i++){
                         try {
                                JSONObject obj = results.hits.getJSONObject(i);
                                String image_url_file = obj.getString("image_url");
                                String base_product_id = obj.getString("BaseProductId");
                                String full_image_path = "https://somedomain.com/somPath/ProductImages/"+base_product_id+"/Original/"+image_url_file;
                                results.hits.getJSONObject(i).put("image_url",full_image_path);
                         }catch(Exception exx){

                         }
                     }
                 }
             }
        );
```

Comment: You can also use the algolia:prefix attribute in the android XML